# Signed URLs on GAE with Python for GCS PUT request

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a signed URL to be used for uploading files directly to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).  I had this working using [POST](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object) using [this Github example](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload), which makes use of a policy.  Per best practice, I'm refactoring to use [PUT](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload) and getting a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT


123456789
/mybucket/mycat.jpg</StringToSign></Error>
```

Per the docs on [creating a signed URL with a program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) and the [GCP example Python code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python/blob/master/gcs-signed-url-example.py), I am doing this process:

1. building my Signature string
2. signing it
3. base64 encoding it
4. url encoding the result (the python example doesn't do this though...

Since this is running on a Google App Engine (GAE) App, I shouldn't need to get a JSON key file for my service account user, but rather use [App Identity Services](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-gae) to sign it.  Here's my code within a Flask project:

```
google_access_id = app_identity.get_service_account_name()
expires = arrow.utcnow().replace(minutes=+10).replace(microseconds=0).timestamp
resource = '/mybucket/mycat.jpg'

args = self.get_parser.parse_args()
signature_string = 'PUT\n'
# take MD5 of file being uploaded and its content type, if provided
content_md5 = args.get('md5') or ''
content_type = args.get('contenttype') or ''
signature_string = ('PUT\n'
                    '{md5}\n'
                    '{content_type}\n'
                    '{expires}\n'
                    '{resource}\n').format(
                    md5=content_md5,
                    content_type=content_type,
                    expires=expires,
                    resource=resource)
log.debug('signature string:\n{}'.format(signature_string))
_, signature_bytes = app_identity.sign_blob(signature_string)
signature = base64.b64encode(signature_bytes)
# URL encode signature
signature = urllib.quote(signature)
media_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com{}'.format(resource)
return dict(GoogleAccessId=google_access_id,
            Expires=expires,
            Signature=signature,
            bucket='mybucket',
            media_url='{}?GoogleAccessId={}&Expires={}&Signature={}'.format(media_url, google_access_id, expires, signature))
```

The `log.debug` statement prints a signature file which perfectly matches the signature in the GCS XML error response  above.  If they match, then why can't I upload?

Using `gsutil`, I can create a signed URL using the same GAE service account, and it works fine in Postman.  I see `gsutil` URL-encodes the signature, but when creating my own signed URL, it doesn't seem to matter either way: GCS gets my PUT request and complains that the signature doesn't match, even though the signature it shows me matches my logged debug message.  I've also tried with and without a trailing \n in the original signature string.

**EDIT:**  The `POST` example I followed [Base64 encodes the Policy before it sings](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload/blob/master/gcs_upload.py#L43), *and again* after it signs it.  I tried this approach with the PUT signature creation and it made no difference

Comment: Are you specifying 'md5' or a 'contenttype' args? It looks like your actual request does not specify them in the request itself. Does the value produced in your debug statement exactly match the value in the `<StringToSign>` element?

Comment: I am not including md5 or content type details in my request nor is it specified in the signed string. So far as I can tell the contents are exactly the same: the string that I signed exactly matches the returned XML value for `SignToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was very close to other answers found on SO and elsewhere noting that a `Content-Type` header needs to be used.  This is partly true, but overshadowed by my main problem:  I was relying on the Default GAE Service Account which has permissions of "Editor" which I assumed could read and write to GCS.  I made a keyfile from that account and used it with `gsutil` which then gave me this clue:

```
myDefaultGAEserviceaccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have permissions on gs://mybucket/cat.jpg, using this link will likely result in a 403 error until at least READ permissions are granted
```

It was right that I'd get an error from GCS when trying to PUT a file there, but it wasn't a 404 error, rather it was the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error shown in the question.

The solution was 2 part:

1. Give the Default GAE service account more permission from the "Storage" set of permissions:

   1. Storage Object Creator
   2. Storage Object Viewer
2. Be sure to use `Content-Type` Header when PUTting the file to GCS because even I don't specify it in the Signature string to be signed, it will default to `text/plain` and require that in  the Header.

**One final observation**: Even after I added the correct permissions to my account, I still got the warning with gsutil until I created a new JSON key file from the IAM console.  Furthermore, signed URLs made with gsutil and the old key file failed to work (`SignatureDoesNotMatch` error) even if the permissions were set on the IAM console.  The Python code running on GAE worked fine without any updates - it only needed the permissions set in IAM and then the Content-Headers to match.